# Filter with a part of input

Tags: javascript

I want a method to find, for example: if we have the name in input like "Gulliver", we need to find all objects in the array that contains that word.

I have this actually :

```
        let data = this.articles.filter(d => d.name.toUpperCase() === this.search.toUpperCase())
```

But it's only finding the word who has been corresponding... between `articles.name` and my text input.

Thank you

Comment: I think if use multiple or statement you get your ans like bellow

Comment: let data = this.articles.filter(d => d.name.toUpperCase() === this.search.toUpperCase() ||  d.contains.toUpperCase() === this.search.toUpperCase()...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `include` or `contains` in your filter.

```
let data = this.articles.filter(d => d.name.toUpperCase().includes(this.search.toUpperCase()))
```

Comment: Thanks mateen .I did not understand the question

Comment: @LDS glad to know my answer helped you, Thanks.